# How can I solve 'Unmatched the Expected Result for CSV File Format'?

Tags: r, csv

I want to make CSV File properly which has separation.
This is CSV File format which is the expected result (CSV File format has separation)
[image: The Expected Result]

but after I type with this code

```
library(rtweet)

api_key <- "..."
api_key_secret <- "...."

token <- create_token(
  app="skrip825",
  consumer_key=api_key,
  consumer_secret=api_key_secret
)
data <- search_tweets("commuterline", n=10000, until='2020-11-02', include_rts=TRUE)
data

write_as_csv2 <- function(x, file_name,
                          prepend_ids = TRUE,
                          na = "",
                          fileEncoding = "UTF-8") {
  ## to minimize rounding
  op <- options()
  on.exit(options(op))
  options(scipen = 14, digits = 22)
  
  ## validate inputs
  stopifnot(is.data.frame(x), is.character(file_name), length(file_name) == 1L)
  if (!grepl("\\.csv$", file_name)) {
    file_name <- paste0(file_name, ".csv")
  }
  ## flatten data
  x <- flatten(x)
  if (prepend_ids) {
    x <- prepend_ids(x)
  }
  utils::write.table(x, file_name, row.names = FALSE, na = na,
                     fileEncoding = fileEncoding, sep=",", dec=".", qmethod="double")
  
  # or
  # readr::write_csv(x, file_name)
}
environment(write_as_csv2) <- asNamespace("rtweet")

write_as_csv2(data,"crawling_commuterline_r.csv")
```

I have problem of the CSV File format result is unmatched the expected result.
[image: Unmatched the Expected Result]

Please give me correction because I am new to R. Thank you

Comment: if you want to make a CSV file, then use `write.csv`, not `write.table` Also you can only save "atomic" types in CSV file. What exactly is in your `data` data.frame?

Comment: I did use `write.csv`, but I still got the same result

Comment: `data <- search_tweets("commuterline", n=10000, until='2020-11-02', include_rts=TRUE)
data                                                      
write.csv(data,"crawling_commuterline_r.csv", row.names=FALSE)`

Comment: can u `dput(data)` and add it to the question because the output of `search_tweets` is a list. as it's mentioned in the question tagged by @MrFlick u could use `write_as_csv `